# How to get all values in multidimensional array

Tags: php

```
Array( 

     [0]=> Array 
         (
          [id] => 1
          [name] => Jane 
          [comment_id] => 1
          [post_id] => 1
        )
      [1] => Array
         (
          [id] => 2
          [name] => john 
          [comment_id] => 1
          [post_id] => 1
        )
      [2] => Array
         (
          [id] => 3
          [name] => anny 
          [comment_id] => 2
          [post_id] => 1
        )
      [3] => Array 
         (
          [id] => 4
          [name] => adrea 
          [comment_id] => 3
          [post_id] => 2
        )
)
```

I want it to be like this

```
Array
 (
      [id] => 1
      [name] => Jane 
      [comment_id] => 1
      [post_id] => 1
    )
     (
      [id] => 2
      [name] => john 
      [comment_id] => 1
      [post_id] => 1
    )
     (
      [id] => 3
      [name] => anny 
      [comment_id] => 2
      [post_id] => 1
    )
     (
      [id] => 4
      [name] => adrea
      [comment_id] => 3
      [post_id] => 2
    )
```

So if I can be able to count all values with the same `comment_id` that is 2 has the same `comment_id`, 1 has `comment _id` with the same `post_id` but when I tried to count each
`$query = mysqli_query " SELECT * FROM reply AS r JOIN comments AS  c ON r.comment_id=c.id";`
I only get this when I print it out please I have been trying  this for days

```
 (
   [id] => 1
   [name] => Jane 
   [comment_id] => 1
   [post_id] => 1
  )
```

So its only printing only one record

It's not giving me all

Comment: What you want is actually what you got!! Your wanted array is actually impossible without being exactly what you are starting with

Comment: Can you post your code? Can help you make changes on the same code!

Comment: Its not really very clear what you want to do with this array. If you make that more clear, maybe we can help you

Comment: I want to get the I'd e.g           forec

Comment: With SQL query, it could be a simple `where` condition.

Comment: I want to get the Ids e.g           foreach ( $comments as $comment) {      Echo $comment['id']; }

Comment: But it's says undefined id

Comment: You have to post your entire code for us to help you. We need to know how you are doing the query loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = [];
foreach( $array as $row ) {
  if($row['comment_id'] === 1) {
     array_push($result, $row);
  }
}
```

when your results are in $array you can get over the first dimension of your array by  the foreach loop. Each entry  ([0],  [1] etc ) on your example will be assign to $row so $row should look like

```
      (
       [id] => 1
       [name] => Jane 
       [comment_id] => 1
       [post_id] => 1
      )
```

Now you look in each entry if the column comment_id matched your wanted value, when it mached put it in a new array $result.

On the end $result should looks like $array ( 2 dim array ) but only have the filtered entries in it. There is also a `array_filter()` function you can look for, but I think this loop is easier to understand

Comment: It says undefined comment_id

Comment: @trimz in that case the array doesn't contain what you think it does / told us it does

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it